# Reorder scrambled H.264 frames with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have a video file that contains an H.264 stream inside an MPEGTS 'container'. I want to extract the video stream without re-encoding it and place it inside a proper container, like MP4 or MKV. The presentation timestamps correctly identify when each frame should play, but they appear scrambled.

At first, I tried this command:
`ffmpeg -i input.h264.ts -c copy output.mp4`
but the resulting video frequently pauses during playback (I assume the player does this to honour the out-of-order presentation timestamps).

I then tried this pair of commands to extract the raw H.264 stream and then place it into an MP4 container without presentation timestamps, but the video (which no longer pauses) now jumps back and forth during playback:

```
ffmpeg -i input.h264.ts -c copy intermediate.h264
ffmpeg -i intermediate.h264 -c copy output.mp4
```

ffprobe has this to say about the original video input file:

```
Input #0, mpegts
Stream #0, Video: h264 (High)
```

I used ffprobe to look a little deeper

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pkt_pos,pkt_size input.h264.ts
```

There are too many frames to show here but I'll try and give an idea of the output:

```
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=10
pkt_pos=100000
pkt_size=9000
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=8
pkt_pos=110000
pkt_size=9000
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=9
pkt_pos=120000
pkt_size=9000
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=4
pkt_pos=130000
pkt_size=9000
[/FRAME]
```

As you can see, the frame position increases with each frame, but the PTS dances around from 10 back to 8 forward to 9 back to 4, etc.

After analyzing every frame's PTS (and watching the `ffmpeg` output without PTS), I can see that every frame is accounted for in the stream, they've just been jumbled around.

Is there an ffmpeg command or option I could use to re-order these frames (based on their PTS) into a watchable video?

Comment: Just to be sure: is the original .ts file playing correctly, or not?

Comment: The original .ts plays the same as my initial attempt at a .mp4; that is to say it pauses during playback. It is my opinion the original file was concatenated out of order but the presentation timestamps remain correct and I wish to use them to recreate a version that's in the presentation timestamp order.

Comment: Inside a packet, the storage order of the frames is not the playing order, but normally the decoder is supposed to put back everything in the right order... I can't help more. Have you tried reencoding instead of just copying?